# IBM Mainframe Assembler program shows extreme jump in CPU Time and Run Time after COBOL call added. Why? What can be done to speed it up?

Tags: assembly, mainframe

An IBM Mainframe Assembler program which reads a very large file was modified to call to a COBOL "stub" program once for each record. The COBOL call is essential, but the program itself does very little work.  A slight increase in CPU was naturally expected, but testing shows a very high increase in CPU usage and run time. Why?  What can be done to speed it up?

Sample source code sufficient to reproduce the problem:

(1) An Assembler program which calls IEFBR14 8192 times:

```
SAMPLE CSECT
       LR    12,15
       USING SAMPLE,12
       LHI   9,8192
LOOP   CALL  IEFBR14
       BCT   9,LOOP
       SR    15,15
       SVC   3
       END
```

Log shows very low resource consumption, reasonable when calling a program which does nothing.

```
EXCP    CPU    SRB  CLOCK   SERV  PG 
  11    .00    .00    .00    603   0
```

(2) Now code a simple COBOL program which does nothing but GOBACK:

IDENTIFICATION DIVISION.
PROGRAM-ID. COBOL.
PROCEDURE DIVISION. GOBACK.

... and also call it 8192 times from within the same loop:

```
SAMPLE CSECT              
       LR    12,15        
       USING CALLCOB,12   
       LHI   9,8192       
LOOP   CALL  IEFBR14         
       CALL  COBOL        
       BCT   9,LOOP       
       SVC   3            
       END
```

Yeow! Now resource consumption is *horrible* by comparison:

```
 EXCP    CPU    SRB  CLOCK   SERV  PG 
65552    .16    .00    .19  3980K   0
```

Comment: are you sure its the COBOL program? also without seeing any code, how can we ever begin to guess where the inefficiency is?

Comment: or any of the before and after stats for that matter

Comment: "are you sure its the COBOL program? " Absolutely. The problem is easily recreatable and will be obvious to anyone who's actually modified an IBM Mainframe Assembler program to call an IBM Enterprise COBOL program.

Comment: Well that's fine to say, but nothing in your question helps us to help you. Just saying there is an increase in CPU time is kind of vague. Give us some before and after stats, give us something to go after. I understand your goal is just to get rep, but you need to start posting question that meet the stackoverflow guidelines.

Comment: removed my down vote. NOW we have a question.

Comment: I once wrote an edit macro in assembler. It didn't' run any faster than the CLIST version as most of the execution time was in the ISPLINK calls.

Answer (score 10):

Since at least the 1990's, standard IBM COBOL, PL/I and Fortran have included a built-in feature called "Language Environment" (LE) which provides a standard set of runtime callable services common to all.  At runtime, this "environment" is established by initialization routines intended to provide a persistent service across all subsequent interlanguage calls.  But while Assembler *supports* LE, it is *not* automatically built-in.  Thus, when Assembler calls an "LE compliant" language such as COBOL, these initialization routines are invoked with *every call*, greatly slowing the process.  The solution is to have the Assembler "driver" program establish the LE runtime environment, so it persists across all subsequent calls and happens only once.  Thankfully, this is easily done by adding a few simple statements to the Assembler source.  While few and simple, placement is crucial. Here is some sample "shell" code which can be used as a template:

```
SHELL CEEENTRY AUTO=DSALEN 
* COBOL CALL can be anywhere after CEEENTRY and before CEETERM 
       CEETERM ,
* declare constants here: 
CONSTANT DC    CL8'CONSTANT'
PPA    CEEPPA  ,  (P)rogram (P)rolog (A)rea
       CEEDSA  ,  (D)ynamic (S)torage (A)rea
* declare variables here: 
VARIABLE DS    CL8
DSALEN EQU     *-CEEDSA
       CEECAA ,
       END
```

There are other LE-related Assembler macros (see link below), but those above are all that are required for a simple, efficient COBOL call.

After adding the essential statements to the Sample program so as to make it "LE Compliant", but keeping the same IEFBR14/COBOL CALL loop:

```
SAMPLE CEEENTRY AUTO=DSALEN                    
       LHI   9,8192                            
LOOP   CALL  IEFBR14                           
       CALL  COBOL                             
       BCT   9,LOOP                            
       CEETERM ,                               
PPA    CEEPPA  ,  (P)ROGRAM (P)ROLOG (A)REA    
       CEEDSA  ,  (D)YNAMIC (S)TORAGE (A)REA   
DSALEN EQU     *-CEEDSA                        
       CEECAA ,                                
       END
```

... now resource consumption is again reasonable for calling an additional program which also does nothing:

```
 EXCP    CPU    SRB  CLOCK   SERV  PG 
   23    .00    .00    .00   1814   0
```

z/OS Language Environment Programming Guide ... Specialized programming tasks 
... Assembler considerations ... Assembler macros:

http://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSLTBW_2.2.0/com.ibm.zos.v2r2.ceea200/clcasm5.htm

Comment: The language runtime (LE) is indeed the culprit, as the original poster's approach causes it to be loaded and unloaded thousands of times. A simple alternative to switching to LE-conforming assembler would be to simply have a "stub" written in any LE language that in turn calls your assembler routine. I often use an empty C program with nothing more than a main() that calls a linked-in assembler routine for exactly this reason.